WooCommerce Rest Api How To Delete Coupon
I USE METHOD DELETE ON THIS ENDPOINT https://mypetstoryapp.com/wp-json/wc/v3/coupons/3601?consumer_key=X&consumer_secret=X BUT I GET AN ERROR 400 -
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Error 400</title>
    <link href="/idea/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="error-container">
        <div class="error-text">
            <h1>Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="error-text-strong">
            <h1>400</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="error-text">
            <h1>Bad Request</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error-descr-container">
        <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


PUT WITH THIS JSON {
"usage_limit":0
} SAME ERROR, BUT GET WORKS FINE

Make sure your consumer_key and consumer_secret have the necessary permissions to delete coupons.
Use CURL to test:
curl -X DELETE \
     https://mypetstoryapp.com/wp-json/wc/v3/coupons/3601 \
     -u consumer_key:consumer_secret


From curl same error 400, without perrmission should be 401, 403 i think

In web app admin panel, on this account i can move to trash and delete pernamently, secretes have read/write access
